# Effects of turning off the browser cache

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

What are the effects of turning off the cache in a browser (for instance, using this method in Firefox):

```
network.http.use-cache - false
```

I'm building an application using PHP and it uses cookies and sessions. Will disabling the cache have any effect on those? Basically what does turning off the cache do in a browser? Will it have some nasty effects? Will it change the behavior of web sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.use-cache):

> When a page is loaded, it can be cached so it doesn't need to be downloaded to be redisplayed. This preference controls whether to cache files retrieved by HTTP or HTTPS either in memory or on disk.

In other words, when this setting is disabled, web pages will always be loaded from the server every time you visit them, as opposed to keeping them cached locally to speed up page loading times on subsequent visits.

This shouldn't affect cookies or sessions.

Comment: True, but I'd like to add that caching is more interesting for images and scripts rather than entire pages. For example, all Super User sites use the same sprites image and the same JavaScript and CSS files. All of those only have to get downloaded once. Disabling the cache makes browsing slower.

Comment: This is just a web application with 20 users and we have our own server so it might not have that much effect if I disable the cache right?